# VS2022 - Can't view values of variables when exception thrown - Local variables and arguments are not available in '[Exception]' call stack frames

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2022

I'm getting an InvalidOperationException thrown (which should be easy to fix). However when the exception is thrown, I can't view any of the current values in the Locals debug window. They all have the same message:

```
Local variables and arguments are not available in '[Exception]' call stack frames. To obtain these, configure the debugger to stop when the exception is thrown and rerun the scenario.
```

Not sure why this is happening (maybe something to do with async?) but this is relatively simple code and I should be able to see the value of these variables.

Comment: So, have you tried to `configure the debugger to stop when the exception is thrown and rerun the scenario.` ?

Comment: Maybe you can create a Minimal, Reproducible Example to help use to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I haven't tried to configure the debugger to stop as I have no idea how to do that. I have reset all exceptions to default but I'm guessing that this means something else....

Comment: Did you try to go to Debug>Windows>Exception Setting and choose "System.InvalidOperationException".

Comment: This is a serious regression.  I'm not sure if it's a VS2022 issue or a .NET 6 issue, but it seriously decreases the usability of the debugger.  It's not always feasible to "configure the debugger to stop when the exception is thrown and re-run the scenario".  In my experience, that is rarely a workable solution. (I see an issue in Github from 2019 - apparently this is yet another serious limitation of the CoreClr that they've chosen to not address).

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT Just take a default install of VS2022 and run any code that will throw an exception, like a code path in which a Linq method is called on a NullReference. It's not particularly hard to run into this dumb issue, which makes it so annoying.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can go to Debug>Windows>Exception Setting and choose "System.InvalidOperationException" to solve the issue.
[image]

Comment: I tried this for a .Net 7 app, but still get the same error. I'm on VS 17.4.2.

Comment: Thank you for posting, but does not seem to work on .net7 & vs2022

Comment: Why does this not work? I still get the same message saying to configure the debugger with absolutely no guidance.

Comment: @JohnGlen Is your exception an InvalidOperationException, as in the original question? If it is a different type of exception, then you will need to enable Break when Thrown on that exception instead.

Answer (score 4):

After some time of searching I stumbled also over your question.

Yes, the accepted answer is a workaround for your problem -> you can go to Debug>Windows>Exception Setting and choose "System.InvalidOperationException" as described in the answer above.

However, this will then break always any "System.InvalidOperationException" even if the exception is handled in a try and catch block.

Alternatively, I suggest you open the "Call Stack window" (Debug > Windows > Call stack).

Here (not sure if this is a new feature in Visual Studio 2022 because in Visual Studio 2019 I don't have this problem) you will see two nearly identical call stacks:

- One starting with [Exception] like "[Exception] ... call stack data ..."
- and another identical but without [Exception] like "... call stack data ..."

If you double click on the second one your local variables are filled - while in the first one with [Exception] your local variables are not filled (which is the default one in case of an exception.

Indirectly this behavior is also described in your error message:

> Local variables and arguments are not available in '[Exception]' call stack frames.

Unfortunately, I've no idea why Visual Studio 2022 now creates two similar call stacks in case of an exception while Visual Studio 2019 doesn't.

Comment: This is the only thing that 'works' for me, and I am also certain that this behavior was not happening previously as I have never had to do this before...

Comment: Where is this second call stack? I see only the one with the frames beginning with "[Exception]". Could you perhaps add a screenshot of the second call stack you're referring to to the answer?

Comment: @reirab it's in the Call Stack window. The lines up top are duplicated below, but without the prefix `[Exception]`.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2022 on a .NET 6 application, I noticed this behavior when the debugger stopped execution during an exception rethrow:

```
try
{
     // some code that throws an exception
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     // some custom exception handling
     throw; // *** This is where the debugger is stopped ***
}
```

My solution, which may not be practical in all cases, was to use preprocessor directives to not catch and rethrow the exception during debugging:

```
#if DEBUG
#else
    try
    {
#end
         // some code that throws an exception
         // *** debugger now stops here, and locals/watch expressions work as expected ***
#if DEBUG
#else
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // some custom exception handling
        throw;
    }
#end
```