# Local variables and arguments are not available in '[exception]' call stack frames

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, exception

I am using Visual Studio Code and .Net 6. When I get an exception in debug mode I can't access the variables. Instead, I get this message

> local variables and arguments are not available in '[exception]' call stack frames. to obtain these, configure the debugger to stop when the exception is thrown and rerun the scenario.

[There is a stack overflow page with the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73608378/vs2022-cant-view-values-of-variables-when-exception-thrown-local-variables) but all the answers are for Visual Studio. How can I fix this issue in VS Code? Do I need to modify launch.json or are there some other settings?

Here are some links that might be useful:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/debugging

Answer (score 1):

I got access to the local values by checking the "All Exceptions" checkbox in the "BREAKPOINTS" section of the debug side bar.

I found that via the VS Code documentation you linked, which has a [Stopping on exceptions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/debugging#_stopping-on-exceptions) section that currently says:

> Checking **All Exceptions** will configure the debugger to stop when an exception is thrown.

which matches the wording of the error message:

> To obtain these, configure the debugger to stop when the exception is thrown and rerun the scenario.